# Using interval in PostgreSQL with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I want to save durations (2 days, 5 years, ...) as intervals in PostgreSQL from my Rails application.

Both duration_min and duration_max are values like "2 days" or "5 years", so each of them is an interval by itself:

```
  def change
    create_table :times do |t|
      t.interval  :duration_min
      t.interval  :duration_max
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

but the DB migration fails when setting the data type to "interval" and rake returns:

```
undefined method 'interval' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition:0x007f8615694360>
```

How do I define the table for it to accept (and understand) an input like "2 days"?

Comment: The original migration now works with rails 5.1.3 (probably >= 5.1):

However, when reading back it still is treated as string, e.g. for
"P1M" or 1.month, the record will hold a string "730:29:06".

Comment: FYI, there's a Rails PR to support deserialization: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16919

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You were close:

```
class CreateExamples < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :examples do |t|
      t.column :duration_min, :interval
      t.column :duration_max, :interval
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Usage example:

```
Example.create duration_min: '2 hours', duration_max: '2 days'
#=> #<Example id: 1, duration_min: "2 hours", duration_max: "2 days", created_at: "2013-12-02 14:20:36", updated_at: "2013-12-02 14:20:36">
Example.where(%[TIMESTAMP ? - TIMESTAMP ? BETWEEN "duration_min" AND "duration_max"], DateTime.now, 10.hours.ago)
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Example id: 1, duration_min: "02:00:00", duration_max: "2 days", created_at: "2013-12-02 14:20:36", updated_at: "2013-12-02 14:20:36">]>
```

Answer (score 2):

We have an implementation of interval for Rails 5.1 that you can try.

https://gist.github.com/vollnhals/a7d2ce1c077ae2289056afdf7bba094a