# Type and naming for a column that represents time duration in seconds

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm creating a Ruby on Rails project with PostgreSQL database

I have a table `test_runs` and I want to add a column to it that represents a duration in seconds. I'm not sure how many numbers will be in front of the decimal point, but I haven't seen much more than 3 or 4.

This is what I'm thinking:

```
create_table :test_runs, primary_key: :run_id do |t|
  t.decimal :duration, precision: 15, scale: 6
  t.timestamps
end
```

1. Is this the most efficient way to store time that needs six decimal points of precision?
2. What should I name this column? I was thinking `duration` or `duration_seconds`

Comment: The most appropriate type would be an [`INTERVAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE), though based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920743/rails-5-and-postgresql-interval-data-type), it looks like a bit of tweaking is required to get ActiveRecord to recognise it.

Comment: @nick what's your opinion on the naming?

Comment: If you're using integers or decimals, including the units in the name is always a good idea. Not necessary for an `INTERVAL`, since it keeps track of its own units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be ahead to store the data in microseconds as an integer. Would only take 4 (or 8 for bigint) bytes per value.  Decimal's take quite a bit more.

> Numeric values are physically stored without any extra leading or trailing zeroes. Thus, the declared precision and scale of a column are maximums, not fixed allocations. (In this sense the numeric type is more akin to varchar(n) than to char(n).) The actual storage requirement is two bytes for each group of four decimal digits, plus three to eight bytes overhead.

Also, SQL operations/math are faster on pure integers.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion. I will try to impliment it and let you know how it goes. I'd love to get your opinion on naming the column. `duration_microseconds`?`duration`?